# Change Variable Values by Form

Tags: php, html, variables

Does anyone know how to change PHP Variable values by HTML Form ? I am using php script to display the values on HTML Pages

> but i want to change the values **by form** not by editing php files but i don't know how to do it

---

here is my php script **[data.php]**

```
    <?php
        $web_title_en = "JDST BLOG"; // Website Title
        $web_subtitle_en = "blah blah blah"; // Website Subtitle
?>
```

and html (for display the values) **[index.html]**

```
<html>
<head>
<?php include 'data.php';?> 
</head>
<body>
<h1><?php echo $web_title_en; ?></h1>
<h4><?php echo $web_subtitle_en; ?></h4>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't use PHP tags in HTML page..

Comment: @RahulK unless the html extension is also handled by PHP which is not an excellent idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to process html forms with php you should read [this w3c tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp). Your form would be something like this:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="data.php" method="post">
Title: <input type="text" name="title"><br>
Subtitle: <input type="text" name="subtitle"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And this would be data.php (a merged version with your index.html)

```
<?php 
$web_title_en = $_POST['title']; // Website Title
$web_subtitle_en = $_POST['subtitle']; // Website Subtitle
?>
<html>
<body>

<h1><?php echo $web_title_en; ?></h1>
<h4><?php echo $web_subtitle_en; ?></h4>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for reply , yes it works but it doesn't store the values if i'm refresh the page the value will gone , my point is wanted to store the value permanently or until i'm submit a new one [with out using sessions and database]

Comment: If you want to store it permanently you will have to use a database or write a file. If you want to store it during the user visit (and the value is different for each user) you can use session variables ( http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp ) (use $_SESSION['web_title_en'] instead of $web_title_en and add session_start(); at the beginning of the php code ).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your exact situation (perhaps the question could be reworded?), but this might be a useful document on how to handle form data:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp